# Right way to provide a component size?

Tags: html, css, angular

Lets say I have a `child-component` that I want to take 70% of `parent-component`'s width.

What is the right approach/best practice in CSS to do that, any why?

in `parent-component`:

```
<child-component class="give-child-width"></child-component>
```

### OR

in `child-component`:

```
<div class="my-width">
    ....
</div>
```

Thanks in advance for any insight!

Any other option with explanation would be highly appreciate

Answer (score 0):

The best method I've found is to wrap the outlet in the relative, and make the outlet 100%.

**parent.component.html**

```
<div class="width-70-percent">
  <child-component class="width-100-percent"></child-component>
</div>
```

The way that Angular renders outlets is dynamic, and artifacts of this can occur if you directly set the width inside the child component to something relative to the parent. In order to ensure that the child always renders correctly you'll need to set the relative size around the outlet, full width on the outlet (and then a full width within the child is still sometimes needed). It may seem extraneous, but it's been the only proven method I've encountered.

Also, I'd highly recommend looking into [@angular/flex-layout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout). While it's still a work in progress, the Angular team has endorsed it heavily and will likely continue to ensure it works as a layout framework for the future of Angular.

Flex layout example:

```
<div fxLayout="row">
    <div fxFlex="70"><child-component fxFlexFill></child-component></div>
</div>
```